# Не видит библиотеку в build.gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Добавил implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:2.2.0' проект не компилируется, и в xml layout не могу подключить элементы интерфейса из библиотеки. Пишет `Failed to resolve: br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:2.2.0` при синхронизации gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по этому PR https://github.com/leandroBorgesFerreira/LoadingButtonAndroid/pull/189 сервер, где либа хранится отключен, а на новый не выложено.

Так что вам или ждать пока автор перевыложит либу (вряд ли дождётесь), либо затаскивать либу простым копипастом исходников, либо искать другой аналог или отказаться совсем от этого.

Comment: спасибо большое! буду искать что-то новое